# Object map is not a member of package org.apache.spark.rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies, rdd

I have executed a `spark-shell` and executed the following instructions:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

def ejemMap(sc: SparkContext) {
   val v1 = sc.parallelize(List(1, 2, 3))
   val v2 = rdd.map(_ * 2)
   v2.foreach(line => println("ejemMap line=" + line))}
```

But I get the following error:

> :37: error: object map is not a member of package
>   org.apache.spark.rdd

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be `v1` in which you `map` over:

```
val v2 = v1.map(_ * 2)
```

`rdd` refers to the package under `org.apache.spark`.